# Windows defender flags .vmdk files from VMWare as virus. False positive?

Tags: vmware, virus, anti-virus, windows-defender

Since like half a year windows defender flags the .vmdk file from vm ware machines as virus.

It will say that it is infected with a form of "BlacoleRef". Strangly is that this doesn't happen with all the files, but just with one of them at a time. I have 10+ vm ware machines but only one got flagged and deleted.

Other people here also having the same issue. It's like every other week someone's VM disc file gets deleted by windows defender.

Is this a false positive from defender? The computers aren't connected together so it can't be a real virus that spreads through the network. Also when googleing the virus it says that this is a javascript virus in your browser that tryes to exploit your browser/java/reader to install other maleware. That doesn't makes sense.

Any idea if this is known or if this is a false positive?

Comment: I had this happen to a Windows 10 VMware Guest machine.  See if you can make or have a backup. Defender deleted (quarantined) the machine and the best solution was to delete it all, restart and restore the backup machine I had. I am not sure what happened inside the machine to cause this, but the backup restored and is running fine.

Comment: Anti-malware utilities will just scan files for binary signatures of known malware.  If your virtual disk contains files that have matching signatures, then those signatures would be embedded within the `.vmdk` file on the host too.  So: 1. Check from within the guest. 2. If you don't want malware within a guest to be flagged by the host, either exclude `.vmdk` files from being scanned or use encrypted VMs.

Comment: @jamesdlin I did perform a full scan in the guest machine, also with the latest  version of defender but it found nothing. So I guess it really is a false positive